# How to check soelim symlink in linux?

Tags: linux

In the `/usr/bin` directory, I noticed that a new symlink named `zsoelim` is created with `soelim` yesterday. We have checked our similar server, but no such symbolic link is present there.

We have not seen such symbolic link before; is there any way to check whether this is malicious?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be malicious, though I would recommend taking the server offline immediately, and then recreating the server from an image that you trust if there is any doubt.

On my Linux system, there is a symlink named `zsoelim` pointed at `soelim`:

`$ ls -l $(which zsoelim)
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 6 Feb 27  2018 /usr/bin/zsoelim -> soelim*`

Note that it's common for Unix programs to be symlinked like this so that the same executable file can have two or more different behaviors, depending on how it is invoked.